# How to delete upto n type of data in self forienkey using django rest framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

```
class Directory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_directory= models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to delete root folder and all the folders which is inside the root folder (root folder means parent_directory is null in Directory model),
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oszCR.png,
In this picture root is base directory and rest of the all folders are inside the root folder and if i delete the root folder then all the folders which is inside the root folder needs to be deleted ]

for exam:

1. root is parent_directory
2. test sub3 and sub4 is inside root directory base on table photo
3. Bhavya is inside sub4 based on photo
4. top is inside in Bhavya

---

Now if I want to delete object number 22 means root directory then 26, 29, 33 and 34 should also be deleted.

---

Would you please let me know how can delete this n type of object without on_delete=models.CASCADE ?

Comment: Well why is using `models.CASCADE` a problem? Looks like the perfect use-case.

Comment: You can use `Collector()` to find the objects that a cascading deletion would delete.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem because I need to create new objects for RecycleBin so i need to create one by one all directory objects

Comment: @coder: then looks like you want to do something like a "soft delete", so with a `BooleanField` that marks if an item is removed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  yes, but I  need to delete those objects from directory model only save directory id in recycle bin model (just for the record)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an iterate script that will collect all the items to remove. This will make *(d)* queries with *d* the *depth* of the subtree, so:

```
from operator import attrgetter


def delete_with_descendants(*directories):
    next_gen = directories = set(directories)
    while next_gen:
        next_gen = Directory.objects.filter(parent_directory__in=next_gen)
        directories.update(next_gen)
    # directories is a set of Directory objects that you can process
    # …
    # remove the directories
    Directory.objects.filter(pk__in=map(attrgetter('pk'), directories)).delete()
```

So you can then delete the directory including all the descendants with `delete_with_descendants(my_directory)`.

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DirectoryViewSet
I am getting this error using your code

Comment: @coder: you are passing the viewset, not the directory itself...

Comment: should i need to pass in this function delete_with_descendants() root directory id right ?

Comment: @coder: no the `Directory` *object* you want to remove...